# Do we end up with multiple Apache/PHP installations when using Docker?

Tags: docker, server, containers, virtualization

I am trying to understand Docker. The idea is that we can create a complete environment and have it run on any machine. But in my mind there is a problem.

Imagine that I create a Apache/PHP/MySQL application where Apache/PHP is on 1) one container and MySQL is 2) another container. Then my friend says - "Hey mate, I just created this really cool Apache/PHP/PostgreSQL application, can I run it on your server?". But he also has a Apache/PHP (different configuration) container and a PostgreSQL container. He DID NOT KNOW that there is already a Apache/PHP container running on the server. That means we will have 2 Apache and PHP installations running on the server.

[image]

If we were not using Docker we could use the same Apache and PHP. Except we would need to install some Postgres extensions. Is my understanding correct? Is this how it is done?

Comment: Yes, that's how it is. That's the entire premise for docker's existence: isolate the running application from other applications.

Comment: "If we were not using Docker we could use the same Apache and PHP" - except for when your friend's app uses a different apache version and/or a different PHP version. Then you'd be in trouble. With docker, this is a non-event.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ok true, but if we end up with the same version? Then we have it twice on the server

Comment: Maybe, but what does it matter? It's a few megabytes on the disk. Disk is cheap. And if you and your friend were building off of the same base image, then docker layer caching would come into play and reduce storage requirements.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev ok, I see. Now I understand that this is normal. I thought I was crazy :D